# display a part of a tab mysql that do not exist in an other tab

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tabs named respectly liste_pieces and client_pieces.

The first contain a list of many elements about 1000. the second contain some element of the first.

Actually I'm doing a query to fullfill the second tab with the first.

Also I would like to display all element from the first that are not in the second.

I've thought I could do a joint pas a joint will only display elements that are in both tab.

And actually that is not what I'm looking for.

I've done that query for the moment

```
      <table id="box-table-a" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" width="50%">LISTE DES PI&Egrave;CES</th>
        <th scope="col" width="50%">AJOUT ?</th>
    </tr>

<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `liste_pieces`";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die;$i=0;
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['libelle'] ; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center" align="center">
  <p align="center">  <input type="hidden" name="piece[<?php echo $i ; ?>]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" name="piece[<?php echo ++$i ; ?>]" id="piece[<?php echo ++$i ; ?>]" /></p></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

But this display to me all elements from the first tab. I do not really know how to remove elements that exists in the second tab.

I have the column id on liste_pices that is the same in the second tab except that it is called id_piece.

I'm a bit lost.

I do not know how to process.

Receive All my utmost Respect.

Kind regards.

SP.

Comment: with 'tab' do you mean 'tables'?

Comment: oh yeah I'm sorry In France I use that word it is the shortcut for table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use queries like this

`"select * from liste_pieces where column_name not IN (select column_name from  client_pieces)"`

and

`"select * from client_pieces where column_name not IN (select column_name from liste_pieces )"`

This will solve your problem, the `column_name` should present in both table with same datatype.

Comment: than you so much I did not know that this kind of request does exist.

Comment: While this will work, a join on the two tables will provide a much more efficient query - avoid functions like `in` wherever you can.

Comment: See http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the trick for you. Yes, it is a join query by the way that you are asking for:

```
select
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col1 // etc
from
    liste_pieces a
        join client_pieces b
            on a.id=b.id_peice
where b.id_piece is null
```

Here is an example from my database:

```
mysql> select id, brand from cars;
+----+-------+
| id | brand |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     4 |
|  5 |     2 |
|  6 |     5 |
|  7 |     1 |
|  8 |     2 |
|  9 |     2 |
| 10 |     5 |
| 11 |     2 |
+----+-------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select id, brand from brands;
+----+--------+
| id | brand  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Ford   |
|  2 | Toyota |
|  3 | Nissan |
|  4 | Smart  |
|  5 | BMW    |
|  6 | Holden |
+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select
    a.brand
from
    brands a
        left join cars b
            on a.id=b.brand
where
    b.brand is null

+--------+
| brand  |
+--------+
| Holden |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also: I just wrote a really lengthy question and answer that covers this exact [sort of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) which I hope will help to clarify how joins work on tables and how to get information from multiple tables in your database!

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped me so much to understand the joint.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Got an example for you that I think will help. While a `not in(...)` query *will* work, it is not efficient to do it - and gets worse with more rows of data.